# innerHTML displays everything correctly except text color and background color

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

JavaScript with Angular 7. Not looking for a way to add color. Looking for a way to display saved colors. I have a rich text editor that saves to the database. It saves the user data correctly and displays as:

```html
<h1><strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><em><u>COLOR TEST</u></em></strong></h1>
```

So I throw it into the innerHTML="{{element.Comments}}". It displays everything correctly as the user puts it in (font size, bold, italics, underline, etc.) but does not show the text color or background color, even though it shows that it is there.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: here is my expected output:
[image: colored text]

And here is current output:
[image: black text]

Comment: can you put an actual and expected output you need?

Comment: Check the console. Angular tells you that it sanitized your HTML and links you to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss). See https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-https-rojzy (check app/app.component.*)

Comment: Chris G that would work but I am not trying to do that for one specific string. I have my {{element.Comments}} call from the API that displays what the user entered into the rich text editor. It displays whatever they entered but doesn't show the text color or background color. Is there a way to do this for whatever they entered? It shows up in the string so that is why I put it into the innerHTML. But now wont show the colors.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Angular was sanitizing the code and not displaying the saved colors that the user was putting in from the rich text editor.

Answer is create a custom pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtml, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeComment',
  pure: false
})
export class CommentPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(items): SafeHtml{
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(items);
    }
}
```

Then in the HTML files that you need it.

```
<div>[innerHTML]="element.value | safeComment"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any innerHTML style to be applied and allow css classes, take a look at ViewEncapsulation.

You have a perfect example at https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation. :)